# How to log last user login in WSO2

Tags: wso2, api-manager

There is a table in our WSO2 DB (SQL Server) called [IDN_OPENID_USER_RPS] and it has a column - LAST_VISIT. I have searched to find a configuration setting that will turn this feature on, but no success. It is used for OpenId. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When users login to OpenID relying party applications where the OpenID authentication is provided by the Identity Server, the login details are stored in this table. USER_NAME column contains the username of the logged in user. RP_URL contains the URL of the relying party where it should be redirected upon successful login. TRUSTED_ALWAYS column contains the value of TRUE or FALSE which indicates whether the user has given the  “Approve Always” or “Approve” options of the application for authentication. LAST_VISIT column contains the date of the last login of the user. VISIT_COUNT is the number of successful login attempts for the user.

Configuration of OpenID can be found here https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Managing+OpenID+Connect